# Image Dataset for basic human actions

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

I need to find an image dataset of human actions including sitting, walking, falling, and standing.

Although I searched, I could only find video datasets.

If anyone could share an image dataset with mentioned categories, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

[Stanford 40 Actions](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/40actions.html#:%7E:text=Stanford%2040%20Actions&text=The%20Stanford%2040%20Action%20Dataset,300%20images%20per%20action%20class.)

The Stanford 40 Action Dataset contains images of humans performing 40 actions. In each image, we provide a bounding box of the person who is performing the action indicated by the filename of the image. There are 9532 images in total with 180-300 images per action class.

**Download**

Please download the dataset using the links below:

- [Images](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/Stanford40_JPEGImages.zip): 297.6MB;
- [Annotation in Matlab](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/Stanford40_MatlabAnnotations.zip): Bounding boxes of humans, one box per image;
- [Annotation in XML](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/Stanford40_XMLAnnotations.zip): Bounding boxes of humans, one box per image. You can use the parser provided by PASCAL VOC to parse the XML files;
- [Image sets](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/Stanford40_ImageSplits.zip): suggested train/test split of the images;
- [All](http://vision.stanford.edu/Datasets/Stanford40.zip): you can download all above files here.

Answer (score 0):

I think Stanford 40 Action Dataset, Flickr and Human Activity Recognition tab of World Data could be reliable sources in this regard. I also found Willow-Actions dataset as a good source.